# Row suppress in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

How to suppress the Row based on dynamically generated column(field)?

Refer image,
marked column dynamically generating. How to suppress the Row if these are empty or zero.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW4UP.png

i have used below formula. But i wont work,

=iif(Fields!Amount.Value is nothing or Fields!Amount.Value = 0, True,false)

Note: Here i have used **Tablix**

Answer (score 0):

If all values in a row for all columns are NULL, SSRS filters away these rows automatically. If one of the columns contains a value the row will be shown, keep in mind 0 is also a value.

You could use something like;

```
=iif(Fields!Amount.Value > 0,  Fields!Amount.Value , Nothing)
```